# theano batched_dot behaves unexpected

Tags: python, numpy, theano

By using theano's batched_dot, but I found something that looks like a bug to me. Transposition of the numpy array makes batched_dot fail, even the resulting shape is correct. Below is my mwe. My questions: should the last line work and is this a bug?

I'm using the bleeding-edge installation which is currently Theano-0.9.0b1.
If required, I can make this an issue on github.

Thanks.

```
import theano.tensor as T
import numpy as np
a = T.dtensor3('a')
b = T.dmatrix('b')

a_np = np.zeros((4,2,2))
b_np = np.zeros((4,2))

bd = T.batched_dot(a,b)
ok = bd.eval({a:a_np,b:b_np})

a_transposed_np = np.zeros((2,2,4))
not_ok = bd.eval({a:a_transposed_np.T,b:b_np})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how `batched_dot` works, but the strides of your transposed array may be throwing it off

```
In [128]: a_transposed_np = np.zeros((2,2,4))
In [129]: a_transposed_np.shape
Out[129]: (2, 2, 4)
In [130]: a_transposed_np.T.shape
Out[130]: (4, 2, 2)
In [131]: a_transposed_np.strides
Out[131]: (64, 32, 8)
In [132]: a_transposed_np.T.strides
Out[132]: (8, 32, 64)
In [133]: np.zeros((4,2,2)).strides
Out[133]: (32, 16, 8)
```

`np.transpose` creates a `view`, changing the shape, strides and order (to `F`), without copying the data.

Does `a_transposed_np.T.copy()` work?

Comment: Thanks, it is the strides, indeed. I just found that other people had the same issue [link](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/2742#issuecomment-219763042)